# Оформление вставной конструкции, соседствующей с придаточным

Tags: пунктуация

> Меня воспитывали питерские художники, и тот подход, который они для
>   меня обнаружили – эта созерцательность по отношению к миру и чёткие
>   критерии по отношению к деятельности *(какой?)*, это умение мыслить
>   отстранённо, опираясь на концепции *(какие?)*, это стремление к постоянному
>   самосовершенствованию, – ещё в юности стали мне близки.

"Какой? какие?" - это мои в скобочках вопросы автору, с остальным я должна справится самостоятельно - с вашей помощью...

Менять ничего нельзя, кроме знаков.

Сделать симметрию зап/тире, закрыв придаточное?

Получилось (изъяв вставку): *тот подход <...> ещё в юности стали мне близки.* Поправить на "близок"?..

Ваши варианты, пожалуйста. Без перестановки/замены слов.

СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меня воспитывали питерские художники, и тот подход, который они для меня обнаружили, – эта созерцательность по отношению к миру и чёткие критерии по отношению к деятельности, это умение мыслить отстранённо, опираясь на концепции, это стремление к постоянному самосовершенствованию, – ещё в юности **стал мне близок.**

1) Знаки ставим симметричные, это допускается, особенно в связи с распространенностью вставки.

2) ...тот подход... стал мне близок.

Answer (score 1):

Естественно, что "**близок**" - иначе конец предложения адресуется ко вставной конструкции, что явная ошибка. Сама вставка очень длинна, поэтому к концу её прочтения трудно вспомнить, "кто близок" (даже автор это забыл, вдобавок различие падежей во вступлении и вставке создаёт ощущение диссонанса) - лучше сразу сказать о *близости подхода* автору, а потом этот подход раскрыть:

> Меня воспитывали питерские художники, и тот подход, который они для
>   меня обнаружили, ещё в юности стал мне близок: (это) созерцательность по
>   отношению к миру и чёткие критерии по отношению к творческой
>   деятельности, (это) умение мыслить отстранённо, опираясь на концепции [=умение мыслить концептуально],
>   стремление к постоянному самосовершенствованию.

Comment: Саша, спасибо за первые две с половиной строки ответа. Ещё раз об авторском тексте: править можно пунктуацию, орфографию, неверно употреблённое слово, пароним например. ПЕРЕПИСЫВАТЬ НЕЛЬЗЯ!